# Issue with docker compose initial DB setup once

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created Docker file which looks like this

```
db:
image: postgres:10.3
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
environment:
  POSTGRES_DB: test
  POSTGRES_USER: test
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: changeme
restart: always
volumes:
  - ./srv/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  - ./init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

I have a sql script in ./init path which have sql commands to create database and user. I see the sql file created in the postgres container but somehow it is not executing. I have followed the documentation on the docker hub. I am not sure what is wrong here?

Comment: I think you should extend the image, the files should be there before the entrypoint finishes execution.

Comment: make sure your file finish by .sql or .sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced this as well. The problem is that the scripts inside of `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` will only be ran if the database has not already been initialized.

If you stop the container, delete the contents of `./srv/postgres/` and then recreate the container your `*.sql` scripts inside of `./init` will be ran.

However doing this will cause your data to be lost.

See [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/411) for a bit more info.