# docker-compose mariadb docker-entrypoint-initdb.d sql is not executed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, adminer

I am attempting to have my docker db container automatically populate the database with a dataset when created. According to the [mariadb documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb/), there is an `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder in the volume that can be used for this purpose.

I set up my `docker-compose.yml` file to mirror examples that I have found on StackOverflow, but am still unable to get my SQL scripts to execute. Here are the relevant pieces of my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.6'
services:

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5.4-focal
    container_name: db
    volumes:
      - ./cms/conf/mysql/data/:/var/lib/mysql/:rw
      - ./cms/sql/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
    restart: always

  adminer:
    image: adminer:4.7.7-standalone
    container_name: adminer
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: always
```

Next to the `docker-compose.yml` file, I have a `cms/sql/init.sql` file with the following contents:

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `test` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 */;
USE `test`;
```

Prior to each test iteration, I clean up any old/cached Docker content:

1. `$ docker-compose down -v` I've found this doesn't actually remove the db volumes. Running a `docker volume ls` still shows past volumes present.
2. `$ docker volume prune` This clears out the volumes. Running `docker volume ls` after running this shows an empty list.
3. `$ rm -rf ./cms/conf/mysql` This cleans out any actual filesystem changes that the db container made.
4. `$ docker-compose up -d --build` To rebuild the containers. This should trigger my initialization SQL scripts.

Docker runs, and the `db` container gets successfully created. I am able to access the `adminer` container running on `localhost:8080`. I am able to log in as the `root` user with the password specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

The Adminer interface shows the standard MySQL databases (`information_schema`, `mysql`, `performance_schema`) and additionally shows the `wordpress` database defined in the `MYSQL_DATABASE` value of the `docker-compose.yml` file. But my `test` database from the `init.sql` is nowhere to be found.

I found some other similar StackOverflow questions that have had similar problems. I've followed the accepted answers, and am still unable to get any SQL scripts to get executed.

1. [docker-compose.yml, postgress, how to setup db, tables and prepop in an init.sql file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729813/docker-compose-yml-postgress-how-to-setup-db-tables-and-prepop-in-an-init-sql/53730572#53730572)
2. [Issue with docker compose initial DB setup once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703184/issue-with-docker-compose-initial-db-setup-once)
3. [mySQL init scripts not running with docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657489/mysql-init-scripts-not-running-with-docker-compose)
4. [Create database on docker-compose startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43322033/create-database-on-docker-compose-startup)

Here's the Docker log from my `db` container. I didn't see anything that looked strange; no error messages about initialization, etc:

```
2020-07-15 19:21:34+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.4+maria~focal started.

2020-07-15 19:21:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2020-07-15 19:21:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.4+maria~focal started.

2020-07-15 19:21:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files



PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER !

To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:


'/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root password 'new-password'

'/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root -h password 'new-password'


Alternatively you can run:

'/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation'


which will also give you the option of removing the test

databases and anonymous user created by default. This is

strongly recommended for production servers.


See the MariaDB Knowledgebase at https://mariadb.com/kb or the

MySQL manual for more instructions.


Please report any problems at https://mariadb.org/jira


The latest information about MariaDB is available at https://mariadb.org/.

You can find additional information about the MySQL part at:

https://dev.mysql.com

Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:

https://mariadb.org/get-involved/


2020-07-15 19:21:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized

2020-07-15 19:21:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server

2020-07-15 19:21:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.4-MariaDB-1:10.5.4+maria~focal) starting as process 107 ...

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE4.2 crc32 instructions

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().

2020-07-15 19:21:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.

2020-07-15 19:21:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2020-07-15 19:21:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.4 started; log sequence number 45041; transaction id 21

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200715 19:21:49

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@5666e0d8e52e' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Warning] 'user' entry '@5666e0d8e52e' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@5666e0d8e52e' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.

Version: '10.5.4-MariaDB-1:10.5.4+maria~focal' socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 0 mariadb.org binary distribution

2020-07-15 19:21:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.

Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.

Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.

Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.

2020-07-15 19:21:58 5 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@5666e0d8e52e' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

2020-07-15 19:21:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database wordpress23

2020-07-15 19:21:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user root

ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'

2020-07-15 19:21:34+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.4+maria~focal started.

2020-07-15 19:21:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2020-07-15 19:21:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.4+maria~focal started.

2020-07-15 19:21:35+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files



PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER !

To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:


'/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root password 'new-password'

'/usr/bin/mysqladmin' -u root -h password 'new-password'


Alternatively you can run:

'/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation'


which will also give you the option of removing the test

databases and anonymous user created by default. This is

strongly recommended for production servers.


See the MariaDB Knowledgebase at https://mariadb.com/kb or the

MySQL manual for more instructions.


Please report any problems at https://mariadb.org/jira


The latest information about MariaDB is available at https://mariadb.org/.

You can find additional information about the MySQL part at:

https://dev.mysql.com

Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:

https://mariadb.org/get-involved/


2020-07-15 19:21:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized

2020-07-15 19:21:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server

2020-07-15 19:21:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.4-MariaDB-1:10.5.4+maria~focal) starting as process 107 ...

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE4.2 crc32 instructions

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2020-07-15 19:21:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().

2020-07-15 19:21:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.

2020-07-15 19:21:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2020-07-15 19:21:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.4 started; log sequence number 45041; transaction id 21

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200715 19:21:49

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@5666e0d8e52e' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Warning] 'user' entry '@5666e0d8e52e' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@5666e0d8e52e' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table

2020-07-15 19:21:49 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.

Version: '10.5.4-MariaDB-1:10.5.4+maria~focal' socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 0 mariadb.org binary distribution

2020-07-15 19:21:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.

Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.

Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leapseconds' as time zone. Skipping it.

Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi' as time zone. Skipping it.

2020-07-15 19:21:58 5 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@5666e0d8e52e' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

2020-07-15 19:21:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database wordpress

2020-07-15 19:21:58+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user root

ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'

2020-07-15 19:21:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.4+maria~focal started.

2020-07-15 19:22:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2020-07-15 19:22:00+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 1:10.5.4+maria~focal started.

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.5.4-MariaDB-1:10.5.4+maria~focal) starting as process 1 ...

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] mysqld: Aria engine: starting recovery

recovered pages: 0% 10% 20% 30% 40% 50% 60% 70% 80% 90% 100% (0.3 seconds); tables to flush: 4 3 2 1 0

(0.0 seconds);

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] mysqld: Aria engine: recovery done

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE4.2 crc32 instructions

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=45069

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables

2020-07-15 19:22:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...

2020-07-15 19:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.

2020-07-15 19:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.4 started; log sequence number 45081; transaction id 21

2020-07-15 19:22:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2020-07-15 19:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool

2020-07-15 19:22:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200715 19:22:02

2020-07-15 19:22:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

2020-07-15 19:22:02 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@5666e0d8e52e' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.

2020-07-15 19:22:02 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded

2020-07-15 19:22:02 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table

2020-07-15 19:22:02 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.

Version: '10.5.4-MariaDB-1:10.5.4+maria~focal' socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 3306 mariadb.org binary distribution
```

[Edit]
I logged into the CLI for the `db` container, and verified that my init.sql script is in the docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder:

```
$ cd docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
$ ls
init.sql
$ pwd
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Anyone have any ideas on what else to check?

Comment: Can you log into container and see if `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` actually contains that SQL file?

Comment: @Distdev, yep! I did log into the CLI interface and run a `cd /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` then `ls -al` and my `init.sql` file is the only file there.

Comment: what is weird is that your log says about some crash recovery. Normally this shuldn't happen. Do you have it each time, even after complete volumes and data cleanup?

Comment: It does seem to happen everytime. I just did another fresh cycle after clearing the volumes, and I still did receive `2020-07-15 19:55:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=45069`. 

Do you think this is indicative of a deeper issue?

Comment: yes, I have seen this issue once before (and it also didn't execute init SQLs), however it was resolved by removing volumes and starting containers from scratch. So if it doesn't help you - I'm pretty much out of ideas. May be you can do similar tests with mysql image instead of mariadb, just to check how that one will behave?

Comment: The workaround from @Distdev helped me solve the issued with the initdb.d sql scripts. Not sure if it's the normal behavoir ATM

Answer (score 8):

I faced an identical issue and I investigated the logs more closely.
I wasn't sure if the following error was related but I decided to get rid of it.

```
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'
```

It seems that `root` user is created by default so I changed the `environment` variable of the user to `user` for example instead of `root`:

```
MYSQL_USER: user
```

After that I built and run the `docker-compose.yml` file and the `SQL` scripts executed succesfuly.

Comment: Same here... changed from `MARIADB_USER=root` to `MARIADB_USER=admin` and the scripts on `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` were executed successfuly!

Comment: same for me when tried on windows MYSQL_USER: root was working but on mac it's not after changing to some other user it worked. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had to reset the data volume otherwise the entry script would not trigger. In this case you would have to delete all contents:

`sudo rm -rf /cms/conf/mysql/data/`

Comment: This did it for me. You can find your volume with `docker volume list` if it isn't linked to your local filesystem.